# How do I work with optional object properties in Typescript union types?

Tags: typescript

So take this example:

```js
type GeneralAPIError = {
  status: "error";
  message: string;
};

type Foo = {
    status: string;
    whatever: string;
}

function wat(): Foo | GeneralAPIError {
    return Math.random() > .5 ? {
        status: "error",
        message: "noooo"
    } : {
        status: "success",
        whatever: "yayyy"
    };
}

const eh = wat();

// This doesn't work
console.log(eh.whatever || eh);

// Neither does this
if(eh.hasOwnProperty("whatever")) {
    console.log(eh.whatever)
} else {
    console.log(eh);
}

// This does, but the "as" is pretty ugly
if(eh.hasOwnProperty("whatever")) {
    console.log((eh as Foo).whatever);
} else {
    console.log(eh);
}
```

What's the best way to declare the return type of `wat()` ?
In real life it makes an API call that can return one shape of JSON for an error (`type GeneralAPIError`) and a different one for success (`type Foo`). The error type is reused for lots of similar functions.

The code at the end to say "if an object has a certain key, do this with it" works fine functionally, but TS says:

> Property 'whatever' does not exist on type 'GeneralAPIError | Foo'.
> Property 'whatever' does not exist on type 'GeneralAPIError'.

for the first two examples. It feels like I should be able to type the function return so `eh.whatever || eh` works. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not change the API of `wat` - either it resolves with a `Foo` or _rejects_ with a `GeneralAPIError`.

Comment: COnsider this utility https://tsplay.dev/WYBYxw for using `hasOwnProperty`

Answer (score 1):

You need a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to check what the type is.

```
type GeneralAPIError = {
    status: "error";
    message: string;
};

type Foo = {
    status: string;
    whatever: string;
}

/**
* this type guard checks if the element is of type Foo.
*/
function isFoo(wat: Foo | GeneralAPIError): wat is Foo {
  return (wat as Foo).whatever !== undefined;
}

function wat(): Foo | GeneralAPIError {
    return Math.random() > .5 ? {
        status: "error",
        message: "noooo"
    } : {
        status: "success",
        whatever: "yayyy"
    };
}

const eh = wat();
console.log(isFoo(eh) ? eh.whatever : eh);
```

Another approach, if you have a simple case, is to use the `in` operator:

```
type GeneralAPIError = {
    status: "error";
    message: string;
};

type Foo = {
    status: string;
    whatever: string;
}

function wat(): Foo | GeneralAPIError {
    return Math.random() > .5 ? {
        status: "error",
        message: "noooo"
    } : {
        status: "success",
        whatever: "yayyy"
    };
}

const eh = wat();
console.log("whatever" in eh ? eh.whatever : eh);
```

Comment: Genius! Had no idea user defined type guards were a thing or that you could use `in` like that. Thanks man :-D